# Is the jmpl and restore instruction order important in SPARC?

Tags: assembly, io, sparc

I read [here](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/%7Echeung/Courses/255/Syllabus/8-SPARC/call+jmpl.html) that a `jmpl` instruction must be **followed by** `nop`.

The SPARC V8 manual tells me that an `rett` instruction must always be **preceded by** a `jmpl` instruction.

But, I haven't been able to find a relation between `jmpl` and `restore` instructions. I am currently working on SPARC V8 architecture and one of the ELF files I encountered has a `restore` right after `jmpl`, while I expected an `nop`. I don't know if this is correct or the ELF (and by extension the SPARC code) is wrong.

Is having `restore` right after `jmpl` correct?

Comment: This is called a *branch delay slot.*  The instruction following a jump is always executed before the jump takes action.  On modern SPARC implementations, it's usually faster to leave these slots empty for CPU design reasons.  I suppose they have hard-coded some common special cases like `jmpl; rett`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I read here that a `jmpl` instruction must be followed by `nop`.

... and the page you linked tells you why:

> So when you program in SPARC, follow every `call` and `jmpl` instructions with a `nop` instruction **to avoid executing an extra instruction unintentially** ...

This means: The `nop` is not a requirement of the CPU, but it is an advise of the author of the web page for programmers to avoid errors.

On another page of [the **same** course](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/%7Echeung/Courses/255/Syllabus/8-SPARC/func-call+ret.html) the author explains that a professional programmer (or a C compiler) would use the following sequence to return from a function:

```
jmpl %i7+8, %g0
restore
```

This means that it is not only allowed to use `restore` in the delay slot of the `jmpl` instruction, but it is even the normal sequence for returning from a function.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `nop`. Just be aware that the instruction after the `jumpl` will be executed, because it is sill in the pipeline. So `jmpl` followed by `rett` executes the `jumpl` *and* the `rett`. Presumably this is an interrupt service routine or similar?